# Illegal Call of Non-static Member Function when Passing by Reference in for Pybind11 Wrapper

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to wrap an iterate method from C++ with a pybind11 wrapper such that one of the values I am passing is changed after it is ran. In the example code, the variable I want changed is k.

Example C++ code:

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example()   {}
    
    bool iterate(double & k, const double i)
    {   
        if (i < k)
        {
            return false;
        }
        _k++;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The wrapper code:

```
ex.def("iterate", [](double k, const double i) { bool b = &Example::iterate(k, i); return std::make_tuple(b, k); });;
```

The error produced when creating the binding is:

```
error C2352: 'Example::iterate': illegal call of non-static member function
```

I am not sure how else I can change the binding code so that k changes in the python code.

Comment: First, do you know why the error is given?  To call a non-static member function, you need an actual instance of `Example` to call it with.

Comment: I understand that. Unfortunately, I can not change the c++ method to be static as it is required to be in the Example class.

Comment: So where is the `Example` object that you created?  That's basically the entire reason for the error.  Forget about Python for a moment -- put together a piece of C++ code where you are calling a non-static member function this way.  Attempting to do that, you will get the idea of why the error exists.  Figure out how to do that in C++, and then the Python issue may go away.

Comment: What is `_k` in your function?

Comment: _k is meant to be k. Sorry for the typo

Comment: I understand why I have the error, but I do not know how else I can create the binding for the method.

Answer (score 1):

To bind member functions with a lambda, you have to accept the instance as an additional parameter. In this case:

```cpp
ex.def(
  "iterate",
  [](Example& self, double k, double i) {
    bool b = self.iterate(k, i);
    return std::make_tuple(b, k);
  }
);
```